# Visual Studio 2012 Profiler wont produce any output (Win 8)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-8, profiler

I searched both the web and stackoverflow and I feel I'm the only one, so probabyl I'm soing something very simple ver wrong. 
I run VS11 (2012) on a Win 8 64 machine and everything is nice and neat, the profiler too seems (!) to work as it should just that at the very end he's never able to show any results. I get an almost empty window which say that there are no data to show.
I used the "Sampling"

What i found browsing the web is a MS article saying the "Sampling" (which I used) is not available, which would explain it, but A) the article was about the Win8 preview and B) I also found some people giving nice examples of using the VS11 Profiler on Win 8 (in Sampling), so I know some people got it working. But how ?

I also tried running VS explicitly as Admin but it didnt make a difference. And yes, Instrumentation *is* working, but thats of no help for our project, we need Sampling.

Answer (score 0):

I am also having this problem (I'm running Visual Studio Ultimate 2012, Windows 8 x64).  It seems that if the program runs very quickly (mine runs under a second), there are no results.  I decided to make it run for a few seconds and the sampling profile worked.  After scouring the internet I have found some unhelpful webpages - but maybe they will report a fix in the future:

A thread on msdn about this issue
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsprofiler/thread/c609d76c-be22-4ffb-858c-73ccab591a78/

A blog saying that you should use Windows 7 to be able to configure anything for sampling (I hoped to be able to turn the sampling frequency down, but that isn't possible).
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/profiler/archive/2012/12/10/the-visual-studio-profiler-on-windows-8.aspx

Comment: Also, this is everything on msdn about Visual Studio 2012 profiler:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264959.aspx